# Move-Item script failed with missing files

Tags: powershell

I have a script below that is intended to move zip files from the source directory to target (both are network shares).  The script was executed and we now have zip files missing in both the target and source for some sub folders.  Is this possible with the script below and could a network connectivity issue during the script execution result in lost files?

```
$sourceDir = 'X:\Production'
$targetDir = 'Y:\IA Landing Area Archive'


Get-ChildItem $sourceDir -filter "*.zip" -recurse | `
    foreach{ 
        $targetFile = $targetDir + $_.FullName.SubString($sourceDir.Length); 
        New-Item -ItemType File -Path $targetFile -Force;  
        Move-Item $_.FullName -destination $targetFile -Force
    }
```

Comment: If this is an automated script (in task scheduler for instance) it's possible it isn't aware of the drive mapping (if it's not logged in / interactive). Perhaps try UNC path instead?

Comment: I would highly recommend including Test-Path for each path to check the availability of both paths before running the rest of the script.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `new-item` in the script?  The `move-item` itself will fail with a reasonable error message if the script doesn't have access rights to `$targetDir`.  And having it in the script raises the possibility that the script crashes between the `new-item` and before `move-item` completes, leaving the possibility of garbage in target.

Comment: And another idea: could either source or destination be members of file replication sets?  I've seen cases where the data is not completely replicated and so not visible to all users.